# Why did Justice League choose the Batcave to hide in?

Tags: dc, tv, dc-animated-universe, justice-league, justice-league-unlimited

In the second-season finale of the *Justice League* animated series *Starcrossed* (last 3 episodes), the Justice League (minus Hawkgirl) was captured by Thanagarians. But they managed to escape the prison ship and decided to stay hidden until they came up with a better plan for freeing the Earth from Thanagarians.

They changed themselves to their secret civilian identities and split up into groups of two. Then they decided to meet in the Batcave.

Why did they choose the Batcave, which was a known place to Hawkgirl? The Justice League knew that Hawkgirl had betrayed them. They knew that she had revealed their weaknesses to the Thanagarian military and given them the access code of the Watch Tower.

Answer (score 10):

#### The Justice League was dealing with a variety of problems which forced their use of the Batcave as their only real choice. All things being equal there simply wasn't any other place capable of providing the resources to resist the Thanagarians effectively.**

- The Thanagarians arrived with a massive fleet lead by one of their leading strategists, Hro Talak. Their technology was far in advance of anything seen on Earth and was easily a match for the Justice League, who were defeated in seconds facing one of the tiniest ships.
- The Thanagarians arrived on Earth knowing all of Earth's defenses, its resources and the strengths of their primary defenders, the Justice League. The only things they didn't know was what Hawkgirl didn't tell them.
- The Thanagarians had already occupied the entire world with their garrison force. They had already instituted a world-wide martial law keeping all humans in their homes.
- Hawkgirl's relationship with Hro Talak forced her to choose between Earth and Thanagar and her loyalties were conflicted. Five years of living on Earth caused her to doubt the mission she was sent to Earth for. When she learns the technology they were using to build a stargate was instead a "hyperspace bypass" which would instead destroy the Earth, she decides to change sides, again.
- Hawkgirl revealed the location of the satellite and its security codes to allow it to be taken over by the Thanagarians. With the satellite capable of being used as a weapons platform, it had already been secured by the Thanagarians and wasn't available to the League.
- **Hawkgirl already knew about the Batcave but held that information to herself. She suspected the League would escape and the more she learned from the Thanagarians the less happy she was. Because of Batman's trophies and technological scavenging the Batcave was the only place technologically advanced enough to offer any effective resistance to the Thanagarians.**

Comment: The first priority of Justice League was to stay hidden from Thanagarian forces & discuss about what Thanagarians were doing on Earth. And, they didn't know what was running inside Hawkgirl's head. So, how did they think that Batcave was a safe place?

Comment: They didn't. They had to trust her. And that didn't matter either. They had no other choice. Everywhere else was too heavily guarded. Batman's cave was 30 miles outside of town and as a result was simply less guarded. The JLA were at the mercy of Hawkgirl. You notice they did not attack her when she showed up at the Batcave. Nor were they surprised to see her. They EXPECTED her to show.

Comment: @Thaddeus while I agree with your answer, there was also the Fortress of Solitude as another possible option.

Comment: 1. There were gazillions of locations to hide in. As a civilian, they could gather in any hotel, tunnel, cave etc. 2. They were surprised to see her. Not sure about Batman, but Superman said something like this: You dare to show up your nerve. Even Diana went into attacking position. They would attacked her if she wouldn't said that she was there to help.

Comment: And, I am unable to understand your point of trusting. She screwed them to the death and brutally hit GL after abusing his feelings for her.

Comment: And your point is what? People screw each other over all the time, on Earth. And other people forgive them for screwing them over all the time, on EARTH. The motivations for the event did not mean they weren't able to consider a possibility beyond what was happening. GL and Hawkgirl (and to the extent an organization like the League works) loved each other. More importantly their lives have been in each other's hands frequently, so when you work that closely, you find you are more forgiving, even when you are MAD AS HELL at that person. It is the nature of the HUMAN/Thanagarian experience.

Comment: You cannot walk to the Fortress of Solitude, Monty. It's in one of the polar regions on the planet. The Thanagarians ruled the air, so there was no flying there for anyone, except maybe Superman who was still weak from the Red Sun bindings on the Thanagarian ship. Their choices were limited. Why does this bother everyone so much? Even the JLA can get caught with their pants down on occasion. Trust makes you vulnerable... If she was truly going to betray them, WHY NOT JUST BRING THE THANAGERIANS WITH HER? She came seeking forgiveness, betraying Hro Talak who betrayed HER trust.

Comment: @Thaddeus fair point about the distance to the Fortress.  Star Labs and Cadmus could also have possibly provided technological aid in resistance.  Like I said though, my answer and your answer are in agreement on the reasons they chose the Cave.

Comment: I considered Star Labs but they don't have much in the way of weaponry and the JLA and Cadmus have never been very friendly. Both of those would have also been in Hawkgirl's report and were probably under close scrutiny as well. Hawkgirl didn't give them up, because she didn't trust the Thanagarians. She KNEW them...

Comment: "There were many support personnel on the satellite." This is incorrect. Throughout the first two seasons, the Watchtower satellite is empty of any personnel; only the Leaguers themselves are on it regularly. It's only in Unlimited where you start seeing a large crew running the daily operations.

Answer (score 1):

While Hawkgirl may have been aware of the *existence* of the Bat Cave, she did not know it's exact location.  Batman was the only person who could allow access to the cave, no one gets in without his or another member of the Bat Family's permission.  It was also a secure location underground, more than likely shielded from the possiblity of intrusive scanning/eavesdropping by the Thanagarians.

From a writer's perspective it also gave them a chance for the League to use some of those nifty trophys Bats keeps there to defend against the Thanagarians once they showed up.

Comment: Looks like you haven't watched those episodes. Hawkgirl did appear in the Batcave (but, not as an enemy).

Comment: You are right it has been a few years since I saw that one, however she still did not know the exact location of the cave, and like I said Batman was the only person who could grant access to it via the League transporters.

Comment: 1. She appeared in Batcave by flying. 2. Batman didn't invite her (means, no authorization). 3. Justice League didn't have transporters at that time. League transporters came in existence after revolution (Justice League Unlimited).

Comment: Her purpose there was to give Batman information, if I remember correctly, and with a few very rare exceptions (Ras Al Ghul, Inque, and I think the Joker), no one gains access to the cave without Bruce or another member of the Bat Family allowing it.

Comment: I also edited my answer to remove the part about transporter access, as I remember now they used the Javelin shuttles to travel to and from the first Watchtower

Comment: Hold on a second.. How are you saying that Hawkgirl didn't know the exact location of Batcave? She reached there *by her own*.

Comment: Which goes to reenforce the point that Bruce allowed her to show up.  It's already established earlier in the story that while he has already deduced everyone else's secret identities they had no idea who he really was until he, in a show of trust unmasks himself.  None of the other Leaguers, with the exception of possibly Clark and Diana, knew the exact location of the cave.

Comment: Hawlgirl may not know that home of Bruce Wayne could lead to Batcave, but she knew the exact location of Batcave, for sure. If this fact was known to Batman and he indirectly allowed the Hawkgirl, main theme of your answer goes on failure.

Comment: The main point of my answer was that it was a secure location.  You can always argue that she did or did not know it's location, but it's an established point in all continuities that only a very select fiew know it's location, let alone can gain access to it, and Shayera was NOT one of those.

Comment: Sorry, Monty, but you're more wrong than right.  All this discussion sent me to watch the episode and pertinent scenes.  The JLA are in deep discussion about the Thanagarians' strategy-purpose when Hawkgirl interrupts, walking out of the shadows.  There is a distinct shot of Diana, John, AND Bruce all with a startled WTF expression.  There is no indication here, or later, that he was pretending to be surprised.  As well, Hawkgirl unknowingly carried a tracking device, which the Hawks tracked easily to the Cave.  So much for the "shielded from intrusive scanning" you postulate.

Comment: Not to bang away too hard, but your assertion that "no one gets in without permission" is swept away in "Starcrossed Pt.3".  The Thanagarian strike team and their weapons have about as much trouble entering the Batcave as I would pulling back a shower curtain.

Answer (score 1):

Other than the Watchtower which was already laid siege, no other hero at the time; possessed a discreet headquarters capable of serving or hiding their actions.
Who else among the League has their own hideout......None. Flash resides in an apartment (his closest approximation is the Flash mobile). Green Lantern has a largely public identity. J'onn and Diana live aboard the watchtower (though Diana is shown having an apartment). Superman has the Fortress, but that would be inaccessible without transportation